# What are possible causes of and solutions to n_jobs=-1 ineffectiveness in RandomizedSearchCV and KNeighborsClassifier in scikit learn?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, knn

I am exploring the hyperparametrs of a KNN model to fit MNIST dataset by using `RandomizedSearchCV` in sklearn.

To do this exploring I kept only 10000 data, otherwise it will take forever.
My code is something similar to this:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
mnist = fetch_openml("mnist_784");
X, y = mnist['data'], mnist['target'];

X_train_pre, X_test, y_train_pre, y_test = X[:60000], X[60000:], y[:60000], y[60000:];
shuffle_index = np.random.permutation(60000);
X_train, y_train = X_train_pre[shuffle_index], y_train_pre[shuffle_index];
del y_train_pre, X_train_pre

X_short, y_short = X_train[:10000], y_train[:10000];
param_grid2 = {"weights": ["uniform", "distance"],"n_neighbors":[3,4,5,6,7,8], };#5,10,15, 20, 25, 30, 40,50]
knn_clf_rs2 = KNeighborsClassifier(n_jobs=-1);

random_search2 = RandomizedSearchCV(knn_clf_rs2, param_grid2, cv=5, 
                                   scoring="neg_mean_squared_error",
                                   verbose = 5, n_jobs=-1);
random_search2.fit(X_short, y_short);
```

To speed up, I set the parameter `n_jobs=-1` both in the classifier constructor and in the `random_search2` constructor, although for the moment I need only the one for the search while the one set in the  classifier constructor is unused. However, [looking around](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58947455/1714692) I saw that according to many people `n_jobs=-1` is ineffective and actually just one processor is used. Even worse, it slows down performances due to the increase resource usage of multiprocessing. So it is actually better to do (in my case too):

```
random_search2 = RandomizedSearchCV(knn_clf_rs2, param_grid2, cv=5, 
                                   scoring="neg_mean_squared_error",
                                   verbose = 5);
```

First of all, is `n_jobs=-1` not working because of the classifier type (KNN) or because of `RandomizedSearchCV` or because of the combination of the two?

Furthermore is there any solution to this such as to force multiprocessing?

Comment: How do you know the n_jobs=-1 in the classifier constructor is unused? Also, if you are sure it is unused, can this process be reversed (If you set n_jobs=-1 in the classifier and keep it out of the other one what happens)?

Comment: I have no clear evidence but the answer to the linked question and the fact it is slower make me think that.

Comment: From looking this issue up I found that when you set the n_jobs parameter to -1, it may slow down the process because of the multiprocessing cost. In some cases when the job is run on a single processor, it can complete the calculation very quickly and the return the result. However running the same job on multiple processors can slow it down due to the multiprocessing cost.

Comment: At this point it seems that you realize multiprocessing may not be as efficient in some cases so it is unclear why you would want to 'force' this. When you are setting n_jobs=-1 you are using multiprocessing it's just slower.

Comment: Because with single process is not fast but takes some time.